# Custom logs in AppEngine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, logging

I have an application for which I would like to record some statistics for later analysis but which are not at all needed within the application itself.  i.e. The data will never need to be read by the application.  Whatever system is used for storing these statistics, I just need to be able to take periodic dumps of the data.

I could use the logging built into AppEngine, but then it will display in the application logs.  I would like to keep the application logs for debugging the application without having to see other custom information every time I check them.

How would you do this?

Edit: More details on the stats.  Each time a user completed a particular task (1-3 times a day) we need to store details about that task. Such as time and order of events.  These would be stored in a single string per session - 1-2kB.

Comment: I'm not sure about AppEngine itself.  Would adding another (custom) logger that writes to a seperate log help?  Or, are you talking about actually serializing data, and then inspecting it later?

Comment: It doesn't specifically have to be within AppEngine (although that would be nice).

Comment: Are you able to provide any more details about the type of stats you're talking about and the frequency of these events?

Comment: @RobertKluin: information added

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a similar logging in my app, and what I did is to set up a simple servlet in a self-hosted server that receives the log string and level and store them in our local database. Each time I need this kind of log, I use asynchronous `URLFetch` to send the data from our app to our logging server.

I could store the log data in the datastore, but then I would lose the option to do full text search of my log strings, which in my experience is invaluable when you're sifting through log files. I could also store the log in an external file and `grep` only the lines that I need.

Answer (score 2):

Your best option is to store this data in the datastore. If you're concerned about latency, you can either use asynchronous operations, and start the write as soon as possible, or you can use the task queue to do the writes offline.

Comment: Wouldn't you run into concurrency problems doing this as it would quickly exceed the 1 write / second (recommended) limit to an entity group?

Comment: @JohnGB: I think you could make the log entity a root entity without any children. This will make each log entity to be an entity group by itself. See the fourth paragraph of http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/entities.html#Entity_Groups_and_Ancestor_Paths

Comment: @IbrahimArief: The log entity will still run into problems if the number of writes to it exceeds the 1/sec.  With log events triggering for every session that a user has, this limit would very likely be exceeded.

Comment: @JohnGB: In the case that I outlined above, the contention issue would only occur if you attempt to perform concurrent write on a single entity at the same time. If you construct new log entity each time you want to write a log, and store it as a new entity on the datastore, you would not encounter datastore contention.

Comment: @IbrahimArief: But then when I have a few million of these entities and I want to do anything with them, I will have to read through a few million objects - not fun.

Comment: @JohnGB: Totally agree with you with the not fun part. And deleting a single log would cost you several datastore writes, potentially costing you tens of dollars when you decided to clear your several million accumulated logs. This is part of the reason why in my answer I prefer to have an external log server rather than storing the log internally in the datastore.